# Need a creature that produces a substances that can be used for illumination

Tags: science-based, biology

In my story there are those creatures that produce this substance. The substance can be used for many things, e.g. as fuel, or source of excellent illumination, etc. This is a pre industrial revolution society.

I'm basically remaking sperm oil. But instead of a whale I want it to be a land creature. Nothing that we consider fish or an animal capable of flying nor can it be a bug.

It should not be too small or too light. Roughly 2.5 meters and 250 kg minimum. Though we should no go crazy with the size as well. I'm just giving somewhat relevant biological limitations to help design the aspect I want.

I imagine it's easily controlled, tends to be in herds. However it has a long pregnancy period. 16-18 month. They are herbivores by the way

Most relevant part is the substance. That is what I need help with.

**Basically what are the plausible and realistic explanations of a creature developing such a substance and in large quantities?**

I left all other aspects up to you because it's irrelevant. If someone wants to have it be produced to cool it down or another says it helps it navigate it's all the same to me.

All I care about is a biological reason for a creature to produce such a substance. Like having a somewhat reasonable biological bases for that.

Comment: What's wrong with the realistic explanation for why whales have blubber in the real world? Why do you need another plausible realistic reason? And you might be mistaking "large amounts" with the animal simply having lots of it because it is large. Other smaller animals have blubber too in proportion to their body size.

Comment: DKNguyen, 
Because all the creatures that have it seem to not fit. They are either fish or birds or something similar. 
I thought that the creature produces a big quantity, relevant to their body size, though I'm still working out the amount and formula of said amount to useful application. 
Though of we want to get pedantic. I suppose the word large is very subjective.

Comment: For a very long time that creature was the olive tree. The classical Mediterranean civilization was illuminated at night with olive oil. Plus it's good to eat.

Comment: _Beeswax_ produced by honey bees is used to make candles also, but you eliminated bugs. 

Comment: @alexp and like all vegetable oils, can be burned in a suitably designed/modified internal combustion engine, or the boiler of a steam engine.  So this is also (except the "very long time" part) true of soybeans, dry corn, sunflowers, rapeseed/canola -- *any* oil crop.

Comment: @Seallussus I suppose if you're after blubber specifically, then the issue is that it's all animals that live in very cold conditions. And that means cold water, not cold air. And it's difficult to be a herbivorous land animal if you live in cold water where nothing grows. Unless you make up a land animal that lives somewhere *ridiculously* cold but you have the problem of needing plants that can somehow grow there as well.

Comment: Possible consideration: Fungi that produce mycodiesel and there are also bioluminescent fungi, so you can combine both ideas and it can be more efficient. I wasn't sure if I should post an answer as fungi are not exactly "creatures", but not plants also.

Answer (score 8):

Cows can be what you are looking for. [Tallow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tallow) was used in the past for making candles.

> Tallow is a rendered form of beef or mutton fat, primarily made up of triglycerides.
>
> Tallow once was widely used to make molded candles before more convenient wax varieties became available—and for some time after since they continued to be a cheaper alternative. For those too poor even to avail themselves of homemade, molded tallow candles, the "tallow dip"—a reed that had been dipped in melted tallow or sometimes a strip of burning cloth in a saucer of tallow grease—was an accessible substitute. Such a candle was often simply called a "dip" or, because of its low cost, a "farthing dip" or "penny dip".

It checks all your points.

Comment: Historically it was mostly sheep rather than cows.

Comment: Basically any livestock you're already keeping for milk/wool/meat and has excess fat that's not particularly pleasant to eat. Sheep's tallow soap is... distinctively scented, if not quite as bad as unprocessed sheep fat. I don't think you'd keep an animal species _only_ for this use though; much more efficient, in that case, to use plant oils (olive, laurel, coconut etc. have all been used).

Answer (score 2):

As @L.Dutch wrote tallow is a good starting point.

If you make the fat on the tail of [this sheep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat-tailed_sheep) a little bit more oily you have what you need. You can also add a little twist: the tail will grow back when it is cut, in this way  you don't have to wait for the calves to grow to have a good supply.

**Alternative:**

If you can grow a bug similar to the [shellac bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerria_lacca) in big quantities you can have an oil with many different possible applications.

Answer (score 2):

Birds have a [gland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uropygial_gland) that produces oils that they rub on feathers to keep them waterproof. The behavior of rubbing this oil on feathers is called "[preening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preening)". [Emu oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emu_oil) is rendered from the fats in their body. As egg layers, they don't have a pregnancy, but oddly enough, male [emus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emu) are the ones that incubate and raise the young. Perhaps on your world, the equivalent to emus are a herd animal that comes from a very marshy & rainy continent. As a result, they produce so much preen oil that they can be milked for the oil. Like our world's flamingos, the oil also contains colorings from what they eat so that the unfiltered oil could be used as a cosmetic.

Answer (score 1):

## Cows

The question is about a 'substance'. That is why cows and methane is perfect. They create gasses as a by product and expell it. Much of which is methane. This can be used as fuel for movement as well as light. They produce it in large quantities and don't need to be killed for the substance. They are herbivores, live in herds, are 2,5m and 250kg+.

Answer (score 1):

**Butter.**

[image: butter lamps]

https://tnp.org/tag/tibetan-butter-lamps/

These are cool little lamps.  They burn clarified butter.

> Tibetan butter lamps are a common feature of Tibetan Buddhist temples
> and monasteries throughout the Himalayas. Traditionally, Tibetans used
> clarified butter from dri (female yaks), but in exile they use ghee.

You can have a butter making animal.  Or a milk making animal, and some of the milk is used for butter.  Might I gently propose the milk be blue and the product of your version of the Star Wars Thala-siren, which looks just like the thala-siren from Star Wars?  You could also use the face of the thala-siren for your own WB stack account picture.  Just thinking out loud in my role as advocate for truth and beauty.

https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Thala-siren

[image: thala siren]